# How can I increase the console resolution of my Ubuntu server

Tags: 11.10, server, grub2, console

I am running an Ubuntu server inside VMware workstation, when I run the VM the screen is really small. I want to increase it to something that fits in the whole VMware console.

I tried changing the `GFX_MODE` in /etc/default/grub, then I ran update-grub2. When I restarted it only made the grub menu HUGE. But once it booted into Ubuntu compltely it shrunk back down to the default resolution.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8):

Try appending `vga=791` to the linux (kernel) line (in `/etc/default/grub`).

See [console Framebuffer](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ConsoleFramebuffer) for additional resolutions (if you want to lower it further).

Comment: To what line in the config file? The link you gave me reffernces /boot/grub/menu.lst. Which does not exist in grub2.

Comment: `/etc/default/grub` , see the " GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash", append it there -`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash vga=791` Then `update-grub` as you did before (undo your previous edit as well).

Comment: Is there a way to specify a resolution like `1024x768x32` for the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`? Or can I only use VESA codes?

Comment: I am not sure with VMWare and your console resolution. You can certainly try it, it will not hurt anything. If that fails, that resolution is vga=824

Comment: look to http://www.pendrivelinux.com/vga-boot-modes-to-set-screen-resolution/ to get an idea of what resolution 791 means. There are other usable numbers there as well.

Answer (score 5):

I used two parameters in /etc/default/grub:

```
# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
GRUB_GFXMODE=1366x768x24
# bug workaround
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

I found the second item by reading the shell scripts in /etc/grub.d.

Be sure to "set pager=1" before running vbeinfo so you can read the output.

Be sure to run "sudo update-grub" when you are done

Comment: Please do not post the same answer for multiple questions.

Comment: It may have been a repeat, but that was useful to me as I reached this page and do not know where his duplicate is.

Comment: In server mode, one should use GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1366x768x24 instead of GRUB_GFXMODE=1366x768x24